# rails selecting attributes on includes tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to write the following query using rails Active Record:

```
select c.name,p.name,SUM(e.hours)
from Events e, Projects p, Unities u, Clients c
where e.project_id = p.id AND 
      p.unity_id = u.id AND
      u.client_id = c.id
group by c.name, p.name, e.project_id
```

Models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unity
  has_many :events
end

class Unity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :projects
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :unity
end
```

I have something like:

```
Event.includes(project: [unity: :client])
```

But I don't know how to specify the selection of attributes and the group by part.

Answer (score 0):

Write your query as below :-

```
Event.joins(:project => {:unity => :client})
     .group("projects.name, clients.name, events.project_id")
     .select("projects.name, clients.name, SUM(events.hours)")
```

Comment: I'm having the folowing output with your suggestion: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>]>. How can I get the values of project name, client name and the event hours?? Thanks